# MySQL if condition null

Tags: mysql, select, if-statement

I am having database columns

---

table name:

- sales
- trans_details

Initially data will be inserted into **sales** lateron when quantity dispatched **trans_details** table get updated

---

columns in sales

- total_quantity
- e.t.c

columns in trans_details

- ordered_quantity
- dispatched_quantity
- pending_quantity
- e.t.c

---

i want to display all the values: 
 - ordered_quantity
 - dispatched_quantity
 - pending_quantity

```
SELECT 
    IF(trans.ordered_quantity!='',trans.ordered_quantity,(sorder.total_quantity)) AS quantity,
    IF(trans.dispatched!='',trans.dispatched,0) AS today_dispatched_qty,
    IF(trans.dispatched!='',trans.dispatched,0) AS dis_qty, 
    IF(trans.Pending_quantity!='',trans.Pending_quantity,sorder.total_quantity) AS pending_qty 
FROM 
    sales as sorder 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN trans_details as trans
```

---

the query is working fine but when the quantity fully dispatched it should '0' but right now it is showing total_quantity... and when i replace `sorder.total_quantity` with '0' in this condition `IF(trans.Pending_quantity='0',trans.Pending_quantity,sorder.total_quantity) AS pending_qty`... initially it is showing '0' but it should show the total_quantity...

---

### sample output:

total_quantity..........dispatched_quantity.......pending_quantity

```
50                    45                    5
 5                     5                    0
 5                     0                    5
```

Comment: Add sample data with output which you want

Comment: Is this output or table data? Add your tables sample data and output

Comment: Please add proper table defnitions. I am not sure why you are doing a character comparison in what should be a numeric field?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have NULL values in your data.  If the issue is NULLs and the data types are numeric, then try this:

```
SELECT coalesce(trans.ordered_quantity,sorder.total_quantity) AS quantity,
       coalesce(trans.dispatched,0) AS today_dispatched_qty,
       coalesce(trans.dispatched,0) AS dis_qty, 
       coalesce(trans.Pending_quantity,sorder.total_quantity) AS pending_qty
```

If these really are strings, then you need to add in a NULL check.  I would encourage you to use `case`, which is standard SQL, rather than `if`:

```
select (case when trans.ordered_quantity is not null and trans.ordered_quantity <> ''
             then trans.ordered_quantity
             else sorder.total_quantity
       end) as quantity,
       . . .
```

And, finally, I am assuming that you just left off the `on` clause by accident.  In any database other than MySQL, you would get a parse error.  But, as a good habit, you should always have an `on` clause when specifying an inner or outer join.